# Using Granite with a different language besides Vala

Tags: applications, gtk, vala, programming

I am interested in developing for elementary OS, but what's holding me back from doing so is that I can't figure out how to use the Granite widgets from C++.  I would prefer to use this instead of Vala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Granite is written in Vala, so it provides a C API which you can use from C++.  Using it should be fairly straightforward; just `#include <granite.h>` in your code, and build with something like

```
g++ -o test test.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags granite`
```

Then, you should be able to use Granite:

```
#include <granite.h>

void do_stuff (int w, int h) {
  GraniteDrawingBufferSurface* bs = granite_drawing_buffer_surface_new(w, h);
  granite_drawing_buffer_surface_clear(bs);
  g_object_unref(bs);
}
```

I chose `Granite.Drawing.BufferSurface` because it's the first class in the VAPI, but you can use any public API this way.