# App development with Ruby in elementary OS

Tags: appcenter, development, programming

Does any one have any prior experience with making gtk3 apps with Ruby, and
the bindings to the apis for ruby (GObject etc)?

Answer (score 2):

This GitHub [repository](https://github.com/cedlemo/ruby-gtk3-tutorial) gives you some basic examples on how to build a GTK app using Ruby. This is example #2 being run:

[image: Ruby&GTK]

Comment: I see that. I'm just wondering how I can use granite in my code. I also found this https://github.com/mvz/gir_ffi

Comment: There's also [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9052/using-granite-with-a-different-language-besides-vala) + [this](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/6/12/calling-c-cpp-from-ruby/).

Comment: Thanks. It appears that FFI performs the best. I'm not sure how far the deviation from vala is but it's better than just using Rubyinline which you might as well you C then. Sounds do able. If I make an app with ruby and gtk3 I'll make a blog post about it somewhere.

Comment: Keep me posted!

Answer (score 0):

Try finding a IRC channel of Ruby, that's the way I do when I program on vala

Comment: I went to the ruby IRC and they said I shouldn't make gtk3 native apps :) They weren't very helpful.

Comment: @notmyrealname hmmm, maybe try on Reddit